# Print XML elements in standard format

Tags: java, xml, dom, xpath

I am using dom parser in Java.

```
<Countries>
<Country name="USA" states="50"/>
<Country name="UK" states="4"/>
</Countries>
```

For the xml given above, if I have USA element node which I want to print as **Country[@name="USA"][@states="50"]**

Is there an easy way to get this done? Or I have to write custom method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use DOM parser , You may need to write the custom method to achieve the above feature.

If you go with JAXB , you can do the above feature by overriding the toString method of POJO class.

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Countries {
    @XmlElement
    Country country;
}


import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute;

public class Country {

    @XmlAttribute
    private String name;
    @XmlAttribute
    private String states;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getStates() {
        return states;
     }
     public void setStates(String states) {
        this.states = states;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return "Country[@name="+getName()+"][@states="+getStates();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you !.